# How do i print something if i don't get a float as an input

Tags: python

```
hours,pay=map(float,input("Enter the numbers of hours and the salary/hour,separated by a space bar:").split())

def computepay(hours,pay):
    if hours >40:
        return ((pay*40)+((((hours-40)/2)+(hours-40))*pay))
    if hours <=40:
        return int(hours*pay)
    if hours and pay != float:
        print ("to bad")


print(computepay(hours,pay))
```

In the function I want to print a negative message if the input is not a float. How do I do that? As you can see I tried something but it didn't work.

Comment: `hours` and `pay` are always `float`s, since you use `map(float, ...)`. You need to *first* catch (try-except) the result of `input` and the conversion to `float`, not later.

Comment: True but I think OP wants to check for float in case the routine is called from somewhere else.

Comment: Anything stopping you from using a try-except (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)? Something like:
try: 
  <your code>
except ValueError:
  print <error msg>

Comment: I don't know why but no answer worked...Can you put me the solution in my actual code so I can see it in context?

Comment: "No answer worked" is too vague: what happened? Also, do you want to check the result from `input()`, or do you want to check just inside your function? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `float()` function to convert inputs to floats, they will *always* be of the correct type when you evaluate them later -- unless, of course, the input is invalid.

In that case, an exception will be thrown. Let's give it a try in a Python shell:

```
>>> float('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: foo
```

So, what you need to do is `try-except` the `ValueError`:

```
values = input("Enter bla bla...").split()

try:
   hours, pay = map(float, values)
except ValueError:
   print "Wrong format!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanna ask Python: "is this a `float`?" or, more generally: "is this an instance of class `float`?"

Here you go:

```
if isinstance(hours, float) and isinstance(pay, float):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `type` function, it is used to get the type of an object and can be used to compare objects by their types.

Examples:

```
type("String") == str (True)
type(1) != float (True)
type(0.3) == float (False)
```

And here is your code edited to use the type function to compare the type of the variables `pay` and `hours` with the `float` class:

```
hours,pay=map(float,input("Enter the numbers of hours and the salary/hour,separated by a space bar:").split())

def computepay(hours,pay):
    if hours >40:
        return ((pay*40)+((((hours-40)/2)+(hours-40))*pay))
    if hours <=40:
        return int(hours*pay)
    if type(hours) != float and type(pay) != float:
        print ("to bad")


print(computepay(hours,pay))
```

Comment: This is usually explicitly recommended against. You want to use `isinstance`. But even better, you should use a exception handling. Python is all about duck-typing.

Comment: Yea you are correct, i'm going to look into updating myself from the type function to isinstance ... I used it because of the habit of using shorten functions and things like :P @juanpa.arrivillaga